# Cannot Locate Google Maps Static Map API Key

Tags: google-maps, web, embed, api-key

How do I obtain an API Key to embed static Google Maps images in my website?

So I want to embed Google Maps images on my site for locations I have the lat and long for. Building the URL is easy enough, but I'm having a world op trouble locating my API Key.

I've enabled the Static Maps API in the console, but the documentation I can find (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) specifies that I should proceed to the Services item in the left-hand menu. However, there is no such Services item in the left-hand menu in the Console. And the screen captures included with the documentation seem to refer to earlier versions of the Console (mine is more modern and responsive--unfortunately, I cannot include a screen capture).

How do I obtain an API Key to embed static Google Maps images in my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the document you have linked is a different API altogether.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#api_key)'s the link for Static Map API key documentation.

Now with regard to locating the API key, you're probably looking at an updated version of Developers Console. On Left go to ***APIs & auth*** instead.
Choose the API(s) you want for your application. **Activate** them.
Then go to **Credentials** on left. This is where you'll find the key.